# Orika - How to disable Mapping for unused Attributes?

Tags: mapping, orika

I have two classes:

```
public class Source {
    String a;
}

public class Target {
    String a, b;
}
```

When I map from source to target the attribute **a** is perfectly mapped. But the attribut **b**, which is not existing in the source, is always set to null. Is there a way to avoid this bahaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When new object is instantiated all attributes are set to null. Orika will set only used attributes the others will keep their null value.